# Google Play submission warning on pickers for accessibility

Tags: c#, google-play, maui, .net-8.0

I'm creating an app with .NET 8 MAUI. I submitted the app to Google Play to publish my app. After the review, I get some warning related to `Picker` elements. In the XAML, I have this code

```
<Label x:Name="lblLanguage" Text="{lang:Translate DictionaryLanguage}" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
        Style="{StaticResource labelEditStyle}">
</Label>
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding SupportedLanguages}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding LanguageTarget}"
        Style="{StaticResource pickerEditStyle}"
        SemanticProperties.Description="{Binding Source={x:Reference lblLanguage}, Path=Text}">
</Picker>
```

From the Google Play Console I get this warning with this [link](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158690):

> This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.

[image]

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: What about the `Title` property?

Comment: I haven't one... `Title` property on the `Picker`?

Comment: Yes.  That looks like it might be whats required.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.picker.title?view=net-maui-8.0#microsoft-maui-controls-picker-title